# Click button to autofill text in Adobe Acrobat

Tags: button, adobe, acrobat

So I need some help writing some code in Adobe Acrobat. The sheet has a row of names on the left side, next to it a signature box, and then a series of boxes where numbers will go. Simply, I need some code that will work so that a series of numbers will be displayed to the right of the person's name when I click a button that is covering their name. Attached is an example of what I need. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1nYr.png)

I have tried using "action buttons" and adding a custom button that would allow me to enter text when clicked, but unfortunately that didn't work. I was hoping that if I clicked a button (as seen in picture) that it would fill out a series of text boxes for me automatically.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I haven't used or created any code yet on how to fix this issue. Again, any help would be greatly appreciated.